# How to delete a selected row of list from csv file in tkinter python?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, selection, delete-row

I am trying to delete the selected row from the selected list in Tkinter based GUI. I don't have any idea how to remove one particular selected row that will permanently remove itself from the CSV file (without creating or with creating backup CSV file) when I click on Delete button. And for that, I will have to write a function but I don't know what to do.

[Here I am attaching the Output GUI I have and What I want to do with it, is marked in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UqPV.png)

[Here is the CSV sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOP87.png)

My Code for selecting the row and showing in list,

```
def show_definition(self, event):
    def_list.delete(0, 'end')
    widget = event.widget
    selection = widget.curselection()
    with open('GRE_Word_List.csv') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        word = []
        meaning = []
        for dictionary in reader:
            word.append(list(dictionary.values())[0])
            meaning.append(list(dictionary.values())[1])
        word.reverse()
        meaning.reverse()

        def_list.insert(0, meaning[selection[0]])
        # print(word[selection[0]])

def delete_word(self):
    x = []
    selection = all_list.curselection()
    print(selection[0])
    with open('GRE_Word_List.csv') as CSVtoDel:
        reader = csv.DictReader(CSVtoDel)
        for dictionary in reader:
            x.insert(0, list(dictionary.values())[0])
    print(x[selection[0]])
```

Comment: A `.csv` is a textfile. While you can in theory remove a line from a textfile, it is difficult and error-prone. The simplest and quickest way to do what you want is to read the file, drop the row you don't want, and write out a new one. I understand your not wanting the trouble of deleting the old copy of the file and renaming the new one. Look at module `in_place` for a nice way to handle that: https://pypi.org/project/in-place/.

Comment: Okay, I will give it a shot, if it can solve my problem and make my code simpler it would be great. Thank you. @BoarGules